# Always show full prompt regardless of window width?

Tags: fish

I have tried a few of the prompts that are available through the fish config tool. All of them have had prompts that become progressively shorter with a smaller window width. I personally don't like this as I always want to see the folder and git branch that I am in.

Is there a simple setting (or a popular off the shelf prompt) that makes the prompt be full width regardless of window width.

Comment: You might consider adding some newlines into your prompt so you can be (more) assured of seeing the info you want to see.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the command `fish_config`, it will open a new tab in your browser, then select the Prompt tab and you will see some pre-setup prompts. If any of those suits you then you need to configure a prompt by yourself. On terminal you can do:

1. Go to `.config/fish` (generally it is located in your home folder. Linux or macOS you can do: `cd ~/.config/fish`
2. Create a folder named functions (`mkdir functions ; cd functions`)
3. Create a file named `fish_prompt.fish` with the content bellow:

```
function fish_prompt --description 'Informative prompt'
    #Save the return status of the previous command
    set -l last_pipestatus $pipestatus

    switch "$USER"
        case root toor
            printf '%s@%s %s%s%s# ' $USER (prompt_hostname) (set -q fish_color_cwd_root
                                                             and set_color $fish_color_cwd_root
                                                             or set_color $fish_color_cwd) \
                (prompt_pwd) (set_color normal)
        case '*'
            set -l pipestatus_string (__fish_print_pipestatus "[" "] " "|" (set_color $fish_color_status) \
                                      (set_color --bold $fish_color_status) $last_pipestatus)

            printf '\f\r> %s%s@%s %s%s %s%s%s' (set_color brblue) \
                $USER (prompt_hostname) (set_color $fish_color_cwd) $PWD \
                (set_color normal)
    end
end
```

Please, note that the code bellow is adapted from the *Informative prompt*

The [Awesome Fish](https://github.com/jorgebucaran/awsm.fish) repository has some interesting [prompts](https://github.com/jorgebucaran/awsm.fish#prompts) that you can install if you like.